# How do I scan a dynamoDB in typescript using aws-cdk-lib?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to write a cdk package in typescript that scans a dynamodb table and uses the contents as an array.  The database is small and only has one column.  I am not using the javascript library aws-sdk, so it doesn't seem like I can use .documentClient.  I have already imported aws-cdk-lib and it seems like I should be able to scan with that.
I know I'm a noob, thanks in advance for your patience and help.

Below is what I have:

```
import * as iam from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam";
import * as ddb from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb";

const table = ddb.Table.fromTableArn(this, 'ImportedTable', 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:111111111111:table/Things');
    table.grantReadData(new iam.AccountRootPrincipal());
    let thing_list = ddb.Operation.SCAN
   
return(thing_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

The CDK does not allow you to directly make API calls against the resources you create. If you want the contents of a table, then you need to use the AWS API to do that. Since you're already using Typescript then check out the Node V3 SDK:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/index.html

You cannot make these calls from within your CDK code as it requires making async calls to the API and that's not allowed from within constructs.

There is a way around it. Something like:

```js
(async ()=>{
   const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({});
   const { Items: items } = await ddbClient.send(new ScanCommand({ ... }));
   
   const app = new App();
   const stack = new MyStack(app, 'MyStack', { someItems: items });  
})();
```

However, I highly recommend you **don't do this**. Primarily because the input to your IaC (CDK code) is now obfuscated, you won't know until you synthesize your stack what the data is and what your CDK code will produce.

In most cases it will be better if you put this API call in another script and save its output as JSON in your repo. Then read that file and pass it over to your CDK code. This way all the data that drives your infrastructure is clearly defined in your repo and code.

Something like:

`getSomething.ts`:

```js
(async ()=>{
   const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({});
   const {Items} = await ddbClient.send(new ScanCommand({ ... }));
   
   fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(Items, null, 2));
})();
```

And then your CDK code:

```js
const items = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json').toString());

const app = new App();
const stack = new MyStack(app, 'MyStack', { ddbItems: items });
```

This is preferred, as it keeps your code deterministic when you run 'synth' as all your inputs are clearly defined in your code.

That being said, if you really insist and understand the risks associated with it, you *can* take the first approach I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, your response is much appreciated.  To be clear, I am not creating the Dynamo DB within the CDK.  Updates to it are separate from the CDK pipeline. I am just reading it to determine the resources that will be built.

Comment: Same applies, the CDK has no mechanism in it to query the dynamodb table for values. You would use the DDB API to do that (via a client, most likely).